# Particular Solution of ODE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, homogeneous-equation

I have an ODE $$m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} +c\frac{dx}{dt} + kx = r(t)$$

Where c is a dampening constant, k is considered a spring stiffness and r(t) is a force.

The first part of my question is to work out a homogeneous solution when m = 1, k = 144 and c = 40.

For this I assumed $$y = Ce^{rt}$$ and $$\frac{dx}{dt} = r.Ce^{rt}$$ and $$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = r^2.Ce^{rt}$$

My final homogeneous solution was

$$y_h = C_1e^{-4t} + C_2e^{-36t}$$

First off, if someone could check this and confirm whether it is correct or incorrect that would be very helpful.

Secondly, the next part is to find the particular solution given $$r(t) = 60 cos (4 π t)$$

I believe the format to answer this is in the form of $$Y_p = A cos (bt) + B sin (bt)$$ However I am not sure about this now how I go about finding the final particular solution anyway. If someone could help me through this that would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Your first result is correct. You need first to solve tha quadratic $mr^2+cr+k=0$ to get $r_1$ and $r_2$ and then $x=c_1 e^{r_1t}+c_2e^{r_2t}$ ($r_1,r_2$ may be complex numbers and then ...).

Comment: You are right about the for of the particular solution (in fact $ b = 4\pi$). Have you seen Variation of Parameters or the Annihilator method? If not just substitute your guess for $Y_{p}$ into the DE and solve for $A$ and $B$.